# Excel 2016 VBA - Creating labels and transferring that to a Word document with a button?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

*edit*
The purpose of this project was to use 1 application to list off a single customer and anywhere from 1-100 serial numbers with barcodes. The data that is in the spreadsheet would then populate a word document (via command button) populate the appropriate sections and print.

I hope this makes things a little more clear.

I am trying to figure out a way to create an excel spreadsheet that contains all of the information and with a command button send the data to word and populate all of the designated spots.

I will include some photos for reference, I did not include all of the serial number/ barcode code because it is the exact same code repeated multiple times.

```
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add("This is my file name", , False)

With wDoc
    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Customer>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("A2")

    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Assembly>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("B2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf


    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<PO>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("C2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Quantity>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("D2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SerialNumber>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("E2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Barcode>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("F2")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SerialNumber>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("E3")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Barcode>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("F3")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SerialNumber>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("E4")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Barcode>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("F4")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SerialNumber>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("E5")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Barcode>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("F5")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SerialNumber>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("E6")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Barcode>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("F6")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf


    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<SerialNumber>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("E7")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf

    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<Barcode>>"
    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
    .Application.Selection = Range("F7")
    .Application.Selection.EndOf



    .SaveAs2 Filename:=("file name goes here"), _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
End With

End Sub
```

[This is the word document that I want to transfer all the data to. It is a template.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyZh0.png)

[This is the excel data that I want to transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9qgI.png)

Comment: Any reason you can't use Word's mail merge functionality?

Comment: I tried using mailmerger, however the instructions were to populate 1 application and automate the printing process to another application. It got really messy when using mail merger with the macros and vb. They also wanted there to be a header and some basic information on the customer.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to add an option to replace all matching token instances, or only one.
For repeated tokens, this allows you to replace one at a time, using different values.

It's not clear what your barcodes are (font? graphic?) but you can likely follow the same approach as for the serial numbers.

NOTE - it's not clear to me that the order of replacements in the serialnumber-Barcode pairs will always be in sync: you will need to test to verify.

```
Sub PerformReplacements()

    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document, c As Range

    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True

    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\twilliams\Desktop\tmp.docx", , False)

    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<Customer>>", Range("A2").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<Assembly>>", Range("B2").Value

    'serialnumbers
    For Each c In Range("E2:E10").Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<SerialNumber>>", c.Value, False '<< one replacement only
        End If
    Next c

    wDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\twilliams\Desktop\tmp2.docx", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False

End Sub

'given a document and a token to replace, replace only one or all of the
'  token instances with "newText"
Sub ReplaceToken(doc As Word.Document, token As String, newText As String, _
                 Optional replaceAll As Boolean = True)

    doc.Application.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    With doc.Range.Find
        .Text = token
        .replacement.Text = newText
        .replacement.ClearFormatting
        .replacement.Font.Italic = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=IIf(replaceAll, wdReplaceAll, wdReplaceOne) '<<<<<edit
    End With

End Sub
```

Note - it would be easier to manage this process if your worksheet also had the token names: you could then loop over the range and perform the replacements without having to hard-code the tokens into your VBA.

Comment: I am sorry about that, the problem is in the word image when the data is transferred over it does not transfer all the data, just in the first column of the table. And I will try this code out, I appreciate it.

Comment: The other issue that I am having is that the data for <<serialnumbers>> is different for every line along with the <<Barcode>> so what you provided me fixed one problem, however it is only copying the first line and populating everything with that line

Comment: Every line where?  In Excel or in Word ?

Comment: In excel.

    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<SerialNumber6>>", Range("E6").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<Barcode6>>", Range("F6").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<SerialNumber7>>", Range("E7").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<Barcode7>>", Range("F7").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<SerialNumber8>>", Range("E8").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<Barcode8>>", Range("F8").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<SerialNumber9>>", Range("E9").Value
    ReplaceToken wDoc, "<<Barcode9>>", Range("F9").Value

Comment: So you worked it out?

Comment: Hold on... making an edit